# Random solid squares appearing in pdf

Tags: pdf, texlive

I have these random solid squares appearing in my pdf files for no reason. I tried to isolate the problem and relate it to a particular type of command. But, I still see them from time to time regardless of what commands I use. Here is an example of a simple TeX input.

```
\begin{itemize}
\item Outer item 1.
\begin{itemize}
\item The code is easy to read/understand given the comments/documentation.
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
```

And below is a snapshot of the pdf that is generated. The funny thing is if I make the text sentence in the inner itemize shorter, it doesn't appear in this case.

[image: Notice the solid square at the end of the line]

I am using Tex Live 2015 on OS X, El Capitan.

Comment: What `\documentclass` are you using?

Comment: not sure why they seem random to you, every line that has the box will have also had a warning in the log saying that it is over full.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The black boxes are generated by overfull `\hbox`es if `\overfullrule` is set. This is usually done by class option `draft`.

Solution:

- Solve the problems with the overfull `\hbox`es.

  Here, `\slash` instead of `/` make it easier for TeX to find hyphenation points:

  ```
  comments\slash documentation.
  ```

  or even

  ```
  comments\slash\hspace{0pt}documentation.
  ```

Workaround:

- Remove option `draft` from the class option list.
- Or set `\overfullrule` to zero:

  ```
  \setlength{\overfullrule}{0pt}
  ```